# check If type is a list returns false

Tags: c#, list, generics

I was trying to process a generic class with properties that are `List<T>`. However it does not work when checking the property using `IsAssignableFrom`.

Code Snippet:

```
var type = model.GetType();

var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
int colorIndex = 0;

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (typeof(List<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
    {
        //codes here

    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Why is it not treating the property as List even it is a list?

Comment: I don't think you can use open generic type that way... Depending on you actual need checking for `IList` may be enough, or check for constructed type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `model` object you have properties with specific types, for example `List<string>`, `List<int>` or something similar. I your code however you are testing for open generic type. These types are not the same, so you do not get a match in `if` statement. To fix that you should use function [`GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) to get underlying open generic type:

```
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
        typeof(List<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
    {
        //codes here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to check if item implements IList so make the check against the "contract" rather than the concrete class :

```
if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, posted from my phone so was I bit fast. Made an update!